# Tensorflow not computing prediction scores

Tags: python, machine-learning, tensorflow, tensorflow-serving

Hey have written some code in tensorflow that i used to predict the sound (sound classification) but when i build i get this as a response without the lables nor the scores 
*the lables are suppossed to be numeric 1-10

```
{
  {
    string_val: "0"
    string_val: "1"
    string_val: "2"
    string_val: "3"
    string_val: "4"
    string_val: "5"
    string_val: "6"
    string_val: "7"
    string_val: "8"
    string_val: "9"
  }
}
outputs {
  key: "scores"
  value {
    dtype: DT_FLOAT
    tensor_shape {
      dim {
        size: 1
      }
      dim {
        size: 10
      }
    }
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
    float_val: nan
  }
}
```

And this is the prediction and classification code

```
classification_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={signature_constants.CLASSIFY_INPUTS: classification_inputs},
    outputs={
        signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_CLASSES:
            classification_outputs_classes,
        signature_constants.CLASSIFY_OUTPUT_SCORES:
            classification_outputs_scores
    },
    method_name=signature_constants.CLASSIFY_METHOD_NAME)

tensor_info_x = utils.build_tensor_info(x)
tensor_info_y = utils.build_tensor_info(output)

prediction_signature = signature_def_utils.build_signature_def(
    inputs={'sounds': tensor_info_x},
    outputs={
        'classes' : classification_outputs_classes,
        'scores': classification_outputs_scores,
    },
    method_name=signature_constants.PREDICT_METHOD_NAME)


print('Exporting...')
legacy_init_op = tf.group(tf.initialize_all_tables(), name='legacy_init_op')
builder.add_meta_graph_and_variables(
    sess, [tag_constants.SERVING],
    signature_def_map={
        'predict_sound':
            prediction_signature,
        signature_constants.DEFAULT_SERVING_SIGNATURE_DEF_KEY:
            classification_signature,
    },
    legacy_init_op=legacy_init_op)

builder.save()
```

Comment: Can you reproduce the NaNs using the same graph without exporting it for serving? If so, I would suggest the [TensorFlow debugger](https://www.tensorflow.org/programmers_guide/debugger) or `add_check_numerics_ops` to figure out which nodes are first creating the NaNs.

Comment: Hey Allen, thanks I found my problem was my variable definitions and I got it showing the Scores. but the classes return "UNK" , would you have an idea to why they return this?

Comment: Are you using UNK for unknown input tokens (sounds?)? I could see those creeping into serving if either (1) there were many UNK tokens in the training data, or (2) the data passed to the serving model is quite different than the training data and the model is confused. The brute-force solution would be to just throw out the UNK label and take the next-highest, but that would remove the model's ability to predict an out-of-sample token. Longer-term it sounds like tokenization or training may need to be tweaked.